# Linux from Scratch - readline-8.1.2 throwing an error

Tags: linux, readline, lfs

I was on my way with installing Linux from Scratch, when I was told to compile and install readline-8.1.2, in chapter 8.11, in LFS 11.1 systemd edition.

I then went and got some old versions of readline, particularly readline-8.1, for LFS 11.0.

When that didn't work, I decided to try this forum, and here I am now. Please help!

Also here are the steps I did:

First off, as chroot, I unzipped the tar.gz for readline with `tar -xf readline-8.1.2.tar.gz`.
Afterwards, I entered the now readline-8.1.2 folder with the `cd readline-8.1.2`

Then, I ran these commands:

```
sed -i '/MV.*old/d' Makefile.in
sed -i '/{OLDSUFF}/c:' support/shlib-install
```

That didn't throw an error. And so didn't this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr    \
        --disable-static \
        --with-curses    \
        --docdir=/usr/share/doc/readline-8.1.2
```

But THIS thew an error!

```
make SHLIB_LIBS="-lncursesw"
```

It threw this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lncursesw: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:177: libreadline.so.8.1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/readline-8.1.2/shlib'
make: *** [Makefile:219: shared] Error 2`
```

Please help; thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of `ncurses` did you install on the system?

Comment: I used version 6.3

Comment: `ncurses` should (maybe) install `libncursesw` if not `ncurses` will need to be recompiled to do so. Then, the `configure` for readline will need to be told where the library and include files for `ncurses` got installed to...

Comment: Thanks! Reinstalled `ncurses` and that fixed it!